# How to read files from specific folders in google cloud using C#

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

The below code is working only for reading all the objects from all the folders in bucket.

```
string bucketName = "testbucket";

// Explicitly use service account credentials by specifying the private key file.
// The service account should have Object Manage permissions for the bucket.
GoogleCredential credential = null;
using (var jsonStream = new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open,
    FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(jsonStream);
}
var storageClient = StorageClient.Create(credential);

// List objects
foreach (var obj in storageClient.ListObjects(bucketName, ""))
{
    //Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);
    var fileStream = File.Create("Program-copy.xml");
    storageClient.DownloadObject(bucketName, obj.Name, fileStream);
    break;
}
```

Comment: As an aside, `GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("credentials.json");` is a simpler way to load the credential file. We've tried to simplify things :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're currently specifying a prefix of `""` which will indeed match all objects.

If you want to specify a folder of, say, "foo/bar", just specify a prefix of `foo/bar/`.

To make sure you don't retrieve items in subdirectories as well, you need to specify the `Delimiter` option. For example, you can use:

```
var options = new ListObjectsOptions { Delimiter = "/" };
var items = storageClient.ListObjects(bucketName, "foo/bar/", options);
```

If you want to include an item for the subdirectory, but not all the contents of that subdirectory, add `IncludeTrailingDelimeter = true` to the options.